# DateRangePicker issue

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, momentjs, daterangepicker

hi i want to use daterangepicker in my page but i am getting following issue that G.Exec is not function could anybody help me
[image]

this is code i wrote and calling function which i made

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    handleDateRangePickers('reportrange', 'SFM_FromDate', 'SFM_ToDate');
    });
</script>
```

and this my function for handleDateRangePickers

```
var handleDateRangePickers = function (DatePickerId, FromDateId, ToDateId) {
debugger
    $('#' + DatePickerId).daterangepicker({
        opens: (App.isRTL() ? 'left' : 'right'),
        startDate: moment().subtract('days', 29),
        endDate: moment(),
        maxDate: new Date(),
        showDropdowns: true,
        showWeekNumbers: true,
        timePicker: false,
        timePickerIncrement: 1,
        timePicker12Hour: true,
        ranges: {
            'Today': [moment(), moment()],
            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract('days', 1), moment().subtract('days', 1)],
            'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 6), moment()],
            'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 29), moment()],
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Last Month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]
        },
        buttonClasses: ['btn'],
        applyClass: 'green',
        cancelClass: 'default',
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        separator: ' to ',
        locale: {
            applyLabel: 'Apply',
            fromLabel: 'From',
            toLabel: 'To',
            customRangeLabel: 'Custom Range',
            daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
            monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
            firstDay: 1
        }
    }, function (start, end) {
        $('#' + FromDateId).val(start.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
        $('#' + ToDateId).val(end.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
        $('#' + DatePickerId + ' span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    });
    $('#' + DatePickerId + ' span').html(moment().subtract('days', 29).format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + moment().format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    $('#' + FromDateId).val(moment().subtract('days', 29).format('DD MMM YYYY'));
    $('#' + ToDateId).val(moment().format('DD MMM YYYY'));
}
```

Comment: please add code for handleDateRangePickers

Comment: @saumil_jariwala i have edited the code